# Visual Studio for Mac will not create a button click handler

Tags: macos, xaml, button, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137301/how-to-add-generate-a-button-click-event-in-xamarin-forms/48137497) but in my case when I type `Clicked=""` and choose the option to create the handler I see this:

[image]

It won't let me create a handler.

Code snippet:

```
<RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Button x:Name="btnAddElder" Text="Add" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=.0000, Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=.3333, Constant=0}" />
    <Button x:Name="btnEditElder" Text="Edit" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=.3333, Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width,Factor=.3333,Constant=0}" />
    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteElder" Text="Delete" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=.6666, Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=.3333, Constant=0}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac does not match the behaviors of Visual Studio for Windows in quite a lot of places. No surprise.

Comment: @LexLi Interestingly it did create the handler for `SelectedItemChanged` OK, just not the `Clicked` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the problem appears to be the way I had named my `Button` elements. They all started with a lowercase letter.

When I use names which start with an uppercase letter, like:

```
 <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Button
            x:Name="AddPublisherButton"
            Padding="10,10,10,10"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=0,
                                                                  Factor=.3333,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Type=RelativeToParent}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=0,
                                                              Factor=.0000,
                                                              Property=Width,
                                                              Type=RelativeToParent}"
            Text="Add"
            Clicked="AddPublisherButton_Clicked"/>
        <Button
            x:Name="EditPublisherButton"
            Padding="10,10,10,10"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=0,
                                                                  Factor=.3333,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Type=RelativeToParent}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=0,
                                                              Factor=.3333,
                                                              Property=Width,
                                                              Type=RelativeToParent}"
            Text="Edit"
            Clicked="EditPublisherButton_Clicked"/>
        <Button
            x:Name="DeletePublisherButton"
            Padding="10,10,10,10"
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=0,
                                                                  Factor=.3333,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Type=RelativeToParent}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Constant=0,
                                                              Factor=.6666,
                                                              Property=Width,
                                                              Type=RelativeToParent}"
            Text="Delete"
            Clicked="DeletePublisherButton_Clicked"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then it does create the handlers! See:

```
void AddElderButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}

void EditElderButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}
void DeleteElderButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}

void AddPublisherButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}

void EditPublisherButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}

void DeletePublisherButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem?view=vsmac-2019

Comment: @LexLi Worked it out.